# How to filter a number from NSString with html tags?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have a following NSString with html tags. I want the telephone number alone from the string.

```
<div><a href="tel:12345" x-apple-data-detectors="true" x-apple-data-detectors-type="telephone" x-apple-data-detectors-result="0">473737474747</a></div>
```

Can some one please help me out in this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess NSScanner could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"<div><a href=\"tel:12345\" x-apple-data-detectors=\"true\" x-apple-data-detectors-type=\"telephone\" x-apple-data-detectors-result=\"0\">473737474747</a></div>";

NSError *error;

NSDataDetector *detector = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];

NSArray * matches = [detector matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSString *phoneNumber = match.phoneNumber;

    NSLog(@"%@",phoneNumber);
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for the great idea. But AFAIK a data detector is made for recognizing data in directly "human readable" documents. Don't know, whether it's working on html tags properly.

Comment: thanks ,data detector is meant for any string in general wether its human readable or html or what ever , and BTY you can detect web links and some other cool stuff check the NSTextCheckingTypes enum for complete list .

Answer (score 1):

This is not done easily, because the data is embedded in a complex structure. Simple changes in the format can influence your code widely. Simply think of the case that the body contains a string of the format "tel:12345", too …

The most robust way to handle that is to use a html-parser.

From where do you get the string?